# Get the most recent record of with unique fields

Tags: sql, ormlite

I have this table in my database, and I would like build a query that will return the records where the date is contained in the last seven days, the number is maximum and records will be group by foo_id. For example:

```
+---------------------------------------------------+
| id | number |            date            | foo_id |
+---------------------------------------------------+
|   0|     29 | 2013-10-01 08:52:00.000000 |      7 |
|   1|     12 | 2013-10-02 08:52:00.000000 |      7 |
|   2|     23 | 2013-10-02 08:52:00.000000 |      2 |
|   3|     42 | 2013-10-02 08:52:00.000000 |      2 |
+---------------------------------------------------+
```

The query would be returns:

```
|   3|     42 | 2013-10-02 08:52:00.000000 |      2 |
|   0|     29 | 2013-10-01 08:52:00.000000 |      7 |
```

I have build this query, but it doesn't work at all:

```
Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
time.add(Calendar.DATE, -7);

QueryBuilder<GreatTable, Integer> qBt = dao.queryBuilder();
qBt.where().ge(GreatTable.DATE_COLUMN_NAME, time.getTime());
qBt.orderBy(GreatTable.DATE_COLUMN_NAME, false).orderBy(GreatTable.NUMBER_COLUMN_NAME, false);
qBt.groupBy(GreatTable.FOO_ID_COLUMN_NAME);
```

And its output is:

```
|   1|     12 | 2013-10-02 08:52:00.000000 |      7 |
|   2|     23 | 2013-10-02 08:52:00.000000 |      2 |
```

Each group by foo_id it must be the record with the maximum number and date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally my query looks like:

```
qBt.where().ge(GreatTable.DATE_COLUMN_NAME, time.getTime());
qBt.groupBy(GreatTable.FOO_ID_COLUMN_NAME).having("MAX(" + GreatTable.DATE_COLUMN_NAME + ")");
qBt.orderBy(GreatTable.DATE_COLUMN_NAME, true);
```

PD: When a date is added there is a little difference, for example 2013-10-02 08:52:00.000000 and 2013-10-02 08:52:00.000010 so the trick is to order by date too.